# How is the formula to determine the angle to launch a projectile to hit a coordinate derived?

Tags: projectile

Wikipedia lists [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion#Angle_%CE%B8_required_to_hit_coordinate_(x,_y)) formula as

> Angle θ required to hit coordinate (x, y)

[image]

It is used to determine the angle at which to launch a projectile in order to hit a coordinate. How is it derived?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start off with the following system of equations describing the $x$ and $y$ motion launched from the origin:
$$
\left\{ 
x=v_0t\cos\theta \atop
y=-\dfrac{1}{2} gt^2 + v_0 t\sin\theta
\right.
$$

Solving for $t$ in the $x$ equation and substituting into the $y$ equation,
$$\implies y = -\dfrac{g}{2v_0^2 \cos^2\theta} x^2 + x\tan\theta$$

From there, I rearrange to get the following
$$
\implies 0 = -\dfrac{gx^2}{2v_0^2} \sec^2\theta+ x\tan\theta - y
$$

Recall the $\tan^2\theta\equiv \sec^2\theta-1$ identity, and use it. Answer should be straightforward from there.

Comment: Ah yes. Thank you for pointing that out. The linked Wikipedia article specifies that the point from which the projectile is fired is $(0,0)$.

Comment: I'm probably wrong but my textbook shows that the x component of motion should be described by x=1/2(vtcosθ) since it is describing the average velocity of the projectile?

Comment: That makes sense, I don't know what I was going on about.

Comment: If x is horizontal, the x component of velocity is constant. You do not need the (1/2).

Answer (score 0):

Write $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ for the projectile. Eliminate $t$ to get an equation relating $x$, $y$, $v$ and $\theta$. Solve it for $\theta$ in terms of $x$, $y$, and $v$. You will need to use a trigonometric identity to express the equation only in terms of $\tan\theta$, and then solve this quadratic equation.

Comment: I can manage to get as far as an equation relating x, y, v and θ (and g?), but am unable to solve for θ. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: The other answer gives the details. I omitted them because I consider it a homework-like problem.

Comment: Yes, the equation also contains $g$ but that is not a value you have any control over so I didn’t mention it.